# Angular material table how to set up different rows each containing a drop down menu

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, local-storage

with a single mat-select I can do it but I can't find the way in a table for that
**when the path changes and the user returns to the table**, keep the last selected values.
*I can save the selected values in localstorage* keeping in mind that the user could
first select a value in the same row of the table and then a different one
for which I apply a *filter to save the last selected values*
but I can't be able to assign the values
selected in localstorage to mat-selects to display after changing paths and back to table
If someone from the community can help me, I appreciate it, *I think there must be a simpler solution than the one I propose.*

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material/select';
interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}


export interface Element {

  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}



const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hugo', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: 2, name: 'Heidy', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
  { position: 3, name: 'Laura', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
  { position: 4, name: 'Bert', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
  { position: 5, name: 'Boroni', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' },
  { position: 6, name: 'Carl', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C' },
  { position: 7, name: 'Nest', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N' },
  { position: 8, name: 'Omar', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O' },
  { position: 9, name: 'Flora', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F' },
  { position: 10, name: 'Nery', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne' },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.css']
})
export class SelectComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  public myForm!: FormGroup;
  selectFood: SelectedFood[] = []
  selectFoodName: SelectedFood[] = []

  selectedValue!: string;

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol', 'validFoo'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  foods: Food[] = [
    { value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak' },
    { value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza' },
    { value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos' },
  ];


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    const localseleccion = localStorage.getItem('selectNames') || 'default-token';
    console.log('localseleccion', localseleccion)
    // valores seleccionados por el usuario si selecciono en una misma fila primero un valor 
    // y luego otro se guarda en el localstorage al ultimo para que si navega a otra pagina al regrear el select //muestre  como valor al ultimo seleccionado y asi con todas las filas 
    // como se puede hacer por ejemplo usando  setValue y el arrObject dar un valor por defecto a todos los select
// o seguramente de otra forma que no encuentro 
    const arryObject = JSON.parse(localseleccion);
    console.log('arrObject!', arryObject);
    /
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      foodControl: [''],

    });


    // this.myForm.get('foodControl')?.setValue('arryObject) como hacerlo ?????




  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {


  }




  doSomething(event: any, row: any): void {
    console.log('Food changed...', row.name);

    this.estado = event.source.value;
    let name = row.name;
    let foodSelect = this.estado;

    let selecciono = { name: name, foodSelect: foodSelect }
    console.log('selecciono!!!!!!', selecciono)

    this.selectFood = [...this.selectFood, selecciono];
    console.log('this.selectFood!', this.selectFood)
    const namesFooSelect = this.selectFood.map(o => { let a = o.name; let b = o.foodSelect; return ({ a, b }) });
    console.log('namesFooSelect!', namesFooSelect)
    const names = this.selectFood.map(o => o.name);
    console.log('names!', names);

    this.selectFoodName = this.selectFood.filter(({ name }, index) => !names.includes(name, index + 1))
    console.log('this.selectFoodName', this.selectFoodName)


    localStorage.setItem("selectNames", JSON.stringify(this.selectFoodName));
    this.selectedValue = localStorage.getItem('selectNames') || 'default-token';
    console.log('this.selectedValue', this.selectedValue);



  }

}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(myForm.value)">
<!--<div class="container text-center">-->
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" #mytable class="mat-elevation-z8">


    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    
    <ng-container matColumnDef="validFoo">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Foo </th>
      
        
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-form-field >
            <mat-label>Favorite Food</mat-label>
           
            <mat-select [disabled]="false" (selectionChange)="doSomething($event,element)" formControlName="foodControl" name='food'>
              <mat-option></mat-option>
              <mat-option [value]="option.viewValue" 
              *ngFor="let option of foods">
              {{ option.viewValue }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
  
    </ng-container>

    

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" >
    </tr>
  </table>

<!--</div>-->
</form>
```